# How would a g2.8xlarge having 4 GPUs be made to act like a single GPU having 16GB of memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, caffe

**g2.8xlarge** instance of **Amazon** have **4 GPUs** with each having **4GB of video memory**. My machine learning algorithm running in **caffe** requires 10 GB of memory at a point in time. Is there any way using which i can make the 4 GPUs act like a single GPU having 16GB of memory. As of now if i try to run my program in the g2.8xlarge instance it will mostly give an error as it will run out of memory.

Any help would be great and any alternatives other than AWS that solves this probelm should also be fine with me but is there any way out using which we can solve this probelm?

Comment: What is your minibatch size?

Comment: its not possible to do what you want. but you can reduce batch size and use multiple gpu training of caffe to achieve similar effect. You will need to adjust learning rate accordingly(eg, divide by #gpu). this is assuming, at minimum batch size, the entire model can fit into gpu ram. if not, you need to get a bigger gpu.

Comment: @ZawLin my algorithm would not work in AWS as i am working with the minimal batch size. Yeah i will need a NVIDIA K80 GPU accelerator basically to solve my probelm. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Although I have never tried it, I believe mxnet has some support for this feature. https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/1639 perhaps you can take a look.